# iframe form killing my table - html

Tags: php, html, iframe, joomla, html-table

I am using a contact form on my website for customers to provide some initial information. In order to try and make it pretty, I am inserting the form (a PHP file) in the right column of a html table, with the information for the customer to read in the left column.

The iframe and form seems to be pushing all the content in the left column down below it's frame.

So far I have tried adding a halign and valign code but Joomla seems to take them out.

Oh yeah, It's a Joomla based website and this is all happening inside an article.

http://purpledevils.com/index.php/services/family-photography

Any help would be muchly appreciated.

Comment: Can you include some code with the specific haligns and valigns that Joomla is not honoring?

Comment: long time browser should know we need to see actual code

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, on your template.
If you add a inline css style to your table column "td" that contains the iframe like position:relative
And add the iframe tag a css style for position:absolute, your content now should be properly aligned.

```
<td style="width: 500px; position: relative;" valign="top" width="500">
    <iframe style="position: absolute;" src="http://www.purpledevils.com/FamilyForm.php" name="form" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" align="left" height="1500" width="490"></iframe></td>
```

Here is an example - http://jsfiddle.net/0yvmt235/